# wrapping dynamic elements

Tags: css

Here is my fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/UxUMG/. 
I have a drop down menu. Parent ul has box-shadow property. When I hover on parent menu item, child ul appears without shadow. What I must do to wrap a whole menu in the shadow?

Answer (score 0):

Change your child class to include the box-shadow property

```
.child {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    box-shadow: 5px 12px 18px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: if i change x-origin in box-shadow property, the shadow has a gap. It is not practical way